# Is it possible to run PyAutoGUI in the background?

Tags: python, pyautogui

I have written a few scripts which uses the pyautogui module in python. I want to understand if it is possible to run the program and the mouse and keyboard simulation with it in the background, where I can parallelly carry on with my regular work.
I tried the follow methods, but failed :
1. Virtual desktop (in Windows 10, but this fails as the mouse simulation or the mouse itself is common between the actual and virtual desktop)
2. Virtual Machine (tried with the VM as well, the mouse simulation seems to fail again)

Please suggest, if there is any other workaround to achieve this. Thank you!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by doing that?

Comment: Is there any chance you are using PyAutoGUI to navigate websites?

Comment: @mkrieger1 The idea here is I have achieved an efficiency improvement on some topics handled at work, between cross-functional platforms. The module basically simulates mouse and keyboard action to do some cyclic/ repetitive activities which would consume a lot of time when done manually. It would be great if I could let this happen in the background and carry on with the regular work on my system. It is now being run when I am not using my laptop.

Comment: @Mandera No not working on navigating through websites. I am using openpyxl to read and write back data to excel and pyautogui module to query the read data from the excel into a standalone platform to fetch data (multiple repetitive clicks and some decision making involved) and then write back the data captured back on to the excel

Answer (score 3):

I have figured out a way by which you can let pyautogui work as well as do all your work at the same time with no VMs.

actually you cant run it in background, but you can do the thing mention above by these steps:-‎‎
‎ㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤ

1. First, you need 2 keyboards and mouse attached on your windows computer.
2. then install this application called mouse mux.
   https://www.mousemux.com/
3. Then turn on 'multiplex input' and multiple keyboard option.
4. Now you will be able to use 2 mouse and keyboards at the same time.
5. put pyautogui in side my side view, and the first mouse and keyboard will be
   controlled by pyautogui and you can use 2nd mouse and keyboard to do something
   else

Note:_

Read the image carefully!.

[image]